# Minecraft 1.8 mod texture issues

Tags: java, json, textures, block, minecraft

So I recently started learning to mod, and it was going well until I hit texturing.  I was able to successfully texture the block in the game itself but something was wrong.  If you got it in your inventory it would come up as a unknown texture instead of the one on the physical block.  Here are my 3 JSON files;

genericDirt BlockState JSON

```
{
    "variants": {
        "normal": { "model": "generic:genericDirt" }
    }
}
```

genericDirt Item JSON

```
{
    "parent": "generic:block/genericDirt",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        }
    }
}
```

genericDirt Block JSON

```
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "all": "generic:blocks/genericDirt"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you need more code, please ask me and i will give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just having to add this render code, oh well, case solved :D

Render Code:

```
if(event.getSide() == Side.CLIENT)
{
 FMLCommonHandler.instance().bus().register(new KeyInputHandler());
 renderItem.getItemModelMesher().register(Item.getItemFromBlock(genericDirt),0, new ModelResourceLocation("generic" + ":" + ((genericDirt) genericDirt).getName(), "inventory"));
}
```